# Why $t(Y)\le l(C_P(Y)$?

Tags: general-topology

See the theorem 1.37. The picture is not clear. Sorry. [See here; May be more clear.](http://picpaste.com/1-1oVdILlp.png)

[image]

> **Theorem 1.37.** If $X$ is a dyadic compact space and $C_p(X)$ is star Lindelöf, then X is metrizable.
>
> *Proof.* Suppose that $X$ is a dyadic compact space and $C_p(X)$ is star Lindelöf. Every Lindelöf subspace of $C_p(X)$ is cosmic by [3, Corollary IV.11.8], so $C_p(X)$ is star cosmic and hence star countable.
>
> If the space $X$ is not metrizable, then some $Y\subseteq X$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor cube $\mathbb D^{\omega_1}$ [2, Theorem 3.1.6]. 
>   Let $\pi_Y \colon C_p(X) \to C_p(Y)$ be the restriction map, i.e., $\pi_Y(f)=f\upharpoonright Y$ for each $f\in C_p(X)$. 
>   Since star countability is preserved in continuous images, the space $C_p(X)$ is also star countable. 
>   Besides, the space $C_p(X)$ is metalindelöf by [6, Theorem 1.2],
>   so it has to be Lindelöf by Corollary 1.5. Therefore, $\omega_1=t(\mathbb D^{\omega_1}) = t(Y) \le l(C_p(Y)) =\omega$ which is a contradiction. $\square$

Why $t(Y)\le l(C_P(Y)$? (in the last line) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Asanov's theorem (see [google book link](http://books.google.nl/books?id=nl3mFq7FzNcC&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=asanov%20theorem%20C_p%28X%29&source=bl&ots=ZbkKeeZMyk&sig=TcCKO366W3j9atH_FLJAGvIi0_U&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2i0-Ub3nCtGg7Ab-hoEQ&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=asanov%20theorem%20C_p%28X%29&f=false) or [this link, theorem 1, countable case](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~tsaban/WIS07/Leiderman.pdf)) that for any Tychonoff space $X$ and any finite $n$ we have $t(X^n) \le l(C_p(X))$. The first link (from Arhangel'skij's book "Topological Function Spaces") has a full proof on page 33, which is quite elementary.